# MySQL database update gives incorrect result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update a field which has a foreign key relationship. As User "Fred" has left the company, I need to change the User field to "exEmployee" for all his transactions. So, I use the following in a ColdFusion CFC:

```
 `UPDATE prodndb.tblReceiptDetails
 SET tblReceiptDetails.UserID = 'exEmployee'
 WHERE BINARY tblReceiptDetails.UserID = '#uName#'`
```

The variable "uName" is set to "Fred" and the SQL finds several hundred entries changing them to "fred" - NOT "exEmployee" as requested. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `BINARY`?

Comment: I understood that Binary enables an exact match including case so that "Fred" won't match with "fred".

Comment: If you have a userid called Fred , that's probably a bad idea

Comment: The user "Fred" is an merely an example. Further testing shows that if, using the quoted SQL, I try to change the user "jackm" to "exEmployee", the result is "JackM"!

Comment: Folks, I've found the problem and it's the nut on the end of the keyboard! The program I wrote to detect users who were not in the master user table was faulty and didn't show that, for instance" the table tblReceiptDetails already contained entries for user "fred" and that those which contained "Fred" were correctly changed to "exEmployee". I shall now retreat and continue with my meal of humble pie.